# find element by tag function is not working in php

Tags: php

I am doing web parsing in php. I have done it successfully but now it is giving me error on find function. Is there any updation in this built i n php function?

Comment: Witch function do you mean in php? `findElementByTag()` is javascript!

Comment: Without seeing any code we will not be able to help you.

Comment: And how about showing your code and the errors, so someone may can help.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The chances, that there's an error in a PHP-function is quite low, compared to if you have made something wrong in your code. :-)

And which PHP-version are you running? If you insert this on your PHP-page, then you'll get your current version:

```
<?php echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion(); ?>
```

If you try writing the code that are giving you the error - and which error your are getting, then it's easier to help. I would have written this in a comment - but I don't have enough reputation-points to write comments yet. :-/

Comment: $html->find("table.prayer-times tr td") as $a

Comment: And the php version is 7.0.15

Comment: Hmm... If I were you, then I would edit your post, and put in those information. It makes it easier for other people to use this question in the future. And possibly write more of the code you have.

Ideally - then also write a chunk of source-code from the other website that you're trying to parse. Then it's easier to see what it should look like. 

And remember writing the error that you're getting. You can try adding this, as well, to your PHP-page:
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`